# Identify Compiler Versions with arm-none-eabi cross compiling

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, eabi

I'm trying to figure out the compiler versions that are used in my project (to sync them across the team).

I'm using ChibiOS on an STM32 and it uses a makefile to compile. In the Makefile it uses

```
TRGT = arm-none-eabi-
CC   = $(TRGT)gcc
```

Which makes it clear that arm-none-eabi-gcc is being used. However unclear to me is, if the version of my gcc compiler (gcc --version) is at all relevant to the compilation. As far a I understand gcc just is being set to a specific target here? Whats the relationship between my gcc/cc executable and the arm-none-eabi-gcc executable?

Comment: There is none.  They are two completely different things with no relationship to each other.

Comment: they are separate toolchains installed in different directories, you can have many many gnu toolchains on your computer at one time, even many gccs and many arm-none-eabi-gccs (in their own directories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relationship. It is a separate compiler which usually comes with its own include files, libraries, startup file and linker scripts. Usually, it is called a toolchain as often it comes with other tools as well (linker, specific versions of gdb and other tools).